# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError: Export 'BioData' is not defined. (16:10)

Tags: react-context

sending props from parents to last child  using useContext. However in the parent/app component const value of createContext not exporting. BioData is const value.

const BioData= createContext();
export {BioData} giving the below error

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\piyal\OneDrive\Desktop\Practice\monday\src\App.js: Export 'BioData' is not defined. (16:10)

tried uninstall and install node and react app, Changing const and syntax but nothing worked.